# What is the syntax for writing a function in Darwin (OS X)?

Tags: bash, darwin

I tried

```
function myfunc() {stuff goes here;}
```

to no avail. Just trying to put a basic sql-dump script in my .profile file.

Comment: If you're putting it in one line, you need spaces on both sides of the opening and closing braces: `myfunc() { stuff...; }` -- the shell is very specific about requiring whitespace there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're actually asking is how to write a shell function. The first question is which shell you're using - the default is bash, but if you're not using bash then the syntax you're using won't work.

If you are using bash, then your syntax is fine. I added the following line to my .profile and it works as advertised...

```
function myfunc() { echo hello; }
```

After adding that to my .profile and creating a new terminal window (it won't work in existing terminal windows unless you re-run .profile), the following outcome:

```
$ myfunc
hello
```

Answer (score 1):

Bash is pretty much the same on Linux and BSD.

[Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide - Chapter 24](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/functions.html) says:

```
function function_name { 
command... 
}
```

or

```
function_name () { 
command... 
}
```

about functions.